# I am having trouble printing numbers

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to do get user input with scanner for salesTotal variable and there is 2 if statements but it does not display my commision rate right.İt gives me 0 for every value that i write.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double commisionRate = 0;
        double salesTotal;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        salesTotal = sc.nextDouble();

    if(salesTotal <=10.000){
        commisionRate = (commisionRate*100)/2;
        System.out.println("the commision rate is : " +commisionRate);

    }
    else if(salesTotal>10.000){
        commisionRate = (commisionRate*100)/5;
        System.out.println("the commision rate is : " +commisionRate);
    }


}
}
```

Comment: `commisionRate = (commisionRate*100)/2;` But `commisionRate` is 0. What do you expect as your output here that is nonzero?

Answer (score 1):

**commisionRate** is a variable that depends from the user input `salesTotal` ,
you are reading the salesTotal  but never using it to calculate the commisionRate

you should be doing instead:

```
 if(salesTotal <=10.000){
        commisionRate = (salesTotal *100)/2;
        System.out.println("the commision rate is : " +commisionRate);

    }
    else if(salesTotal>10.000){
        commisionRate = (salesTotal *100)/5;
        System.out.println("the commision rate is : " +commisionRate);
    }
```